# Where should we direct users asking questions on technical support for modded games?

Tags: support, allowed-questions, site-policies, minecraft

[I was recently informed that questions involving Minecraft mods are off-topic](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28058783#28058783). As a new user to Arqade who is attempting to help out the community, where should I direct users asking questions on this information?

To be specific, I am referring to questions involving mod-specific crashes, not "gimmeh teh codez" questions.

Comment: It might be true in this particular case, but generally don't take one chat message (from someone who isn't even a moderator) as a blanket statement of site policy. That said, I don't think there is a designated SE site to send questions regarding modded Minecraft crashes.  I would suggest the forums for said mod.  Do note, however, that mod related questions that aren't technical support are perfectly acceptable.

Comment: The related meta is [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/minecraft-crash-questions-should-be-made-off-topic-yes-no). There is no other Stack Exchange for these questions because they are not off-topic because we don't like them. They are off-topic because they *just don't work* as questions in the StackExchange format.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to, you direct them to ask the mod creators for support.  Beyond that, there's not really much we can do for them.